# Troubles with deploys with nginx or deploying in development and production environment

Tags: nginx, port, environment, nginx-reverse-proxy, endpoint

I'm having problems when deploying with nginx. I have two environments deployed, production and development. These environments deploy a database and a database viewer for each. My problem is that when configuring nginx or configuring the environment variables, I don't know why the endpoints point to the same database. I am using prisma too, could someone help me?

I have tried separating the databases, changing some ports but what I have not tried I do not even know if I have to have the API running on two different ports so that it does not have interference from endpoints.